# Display a color ramp legend (of a vector layer) in the QGIS map composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, vector-layer

I would like to have a color ramp instead of 10 categories of color when displaying my vector layer in the map composer of QGIS. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I use this plugin to generate color scale bars:
http://www.bc-consult.com/free/bccscbar.html

It takes in .qml files (or looks directly at a raster) and produces an image file. You could then put it somehow in the map composer.

Comment: The asker specifically mentions that he is dealing with a vector layer, not a raster.